# Pagination link not work properly?

Tags: pagination

Pagination not work properly?

I saved this code in "Forum-Com.php" file and when i open this file, pagination works properly and correctly but when I include this file in another page, its open first page correctly but when I click second or another page link it open same comments which are on first page. Please help me. ( I am using Scriptsmill comments script v1.06 and function make_pages_string from admin.php )

```
 $COM_CONF['full_path'] = dirname(__FILE__);


 function make_pages_string ($all_count, $records_per_page, $cur_page, $base_url) {

if ($all_count > $records_per_page) {
    if ($cur_page > 0) { $cur_page=$cur_page-1; }
    $first_record = ($cur_page) * $records_per_page;
    $limit_string = "LIMIT $first_record, $records_per_page";
    $pages=$all_count/$records_per_page;
    if ($pages > (int) $pages) { $pages=(int)$pages+1; }
}
if ($pages>1) {
    $pages_string.="Page: ";
    if ($cur_page>10 && $pages>20) { $first_page=$cur_page-9; }
    else { $first_page=1; }
    if ($pages>20 && ($cur_page+10)<$pages) { $last_page=$first_page+19; }
    else { $last_page=$pages; }
    if ($cur_page+1>1) {
        $prev=$cur_page;
        $pages_string.="<a href='$base_url&page=$prev'>&lt</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
    }
    for ($i=$first_page; $i<=$last_page; $i++){
        if ($i != $cur_page+1) {
            $pages_string.="<a href='$base_url&page=$i'>$i</a>&nbsp; ";
        }
        else {
            $pages_string.="<b>$i</b>&nbsp; ";
        }
    }
    if ($cur_page+1<$pages) {
        $next=$cur_page+2;
            $pages_string.="<a href='$base_url&page=$next'>&gt</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
        }                                     

}
return array ($pages_string, $limit_string);
 }



 function smcom_view()
 {
  global $comments_db_link, $COM_CONF, $COM_LANG;

$result = mysql_query("select COUNT(id) from {$COM_CONF['dbmaintable']}", $comments_db_link);
list ($all_count) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
list ($pages_string, $limit_string) = make_pages_string ($all_count, 10, $_REQUEST['page'], "{$COM_CONF['base_url']}?action=view");

$result = mysql_query("select time, text, author, email, dont_show_email from {$COM_CONF['dbmaintable']} order by time {$COM_CONF['sort_order']} $limit_string", $comments_db_link);


$comments_count=0;
$id=$time=$text=$author=$email=$dont_show_email=$ip=array();
while (list($id[$comments_count], $time[$comments_count], $text[$comments_count], $author[$comments_count], $email[$comments_count], $dont_show_email[$comments_count], $ip[$comments_count])=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $comments_count++;
}

  require("{$COM_CONF['full_path']}/templates/Forum-default.php");

  }
```

Comment: @Sajid, now it is working properly. But one moor problem is that, when I use "mysql_escape_string" it is not work, only first page shows comments with limit and page links but second or other pages not shows comments or pagination link, only says "No comments yet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code given above has no problem at all. The problem is with the server configuration which turned off $_REQUEST global variable from direct access.

Comment: I have one more problem, when someone adding comment on certain page, it shows correctly but when someone comment on second or so on page of that certain page, the comment never shows. Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you.